# How to include '#' pound sign or hashtag to be read as part of a field?

Tags: regex, yaml

I have my yml file looking like this:

```
  fields:
    MC Number: \s+\d+
    BOL \#: \s+[0-9A-Z]
```

But the whole line is not colored correctly as shown in the picture, meaning that it's still being read from `MC Number`.

I tried adding quotes on the hashtag ("#") but it still wouldn't work. Obviously, leaving it without the backwards slash, everything starting at the hashtag would be commented out on that line.

Marked in red is the problem field, it looks green through the whole line:

[image]

Comment: The problem is most likely broken syntax highlighting in your code editor. When I add your definition in VS Code the code highlighting is correct. Moreover, according to YAML Lint your definition is valid!

Comment: This looks like a real corner case due to the backslash in front of the hash symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking this probably is a bug in the syntax highlighter, but one you might work around simply.

I'm assuming you put the backslash in front of the hash to prevent it from being treated as a comment delimiter.   The problem is that backslash escapes only works for characters within quotes.

I'd suggest you put quotes around the "BOL #".  Inside quotes backslash escaping the # is not needed.

Putting it all together, line with the error should probably read:

`"BOL #": \s+[0-9A-Z]`

.